# Ограничение на создание объектов одного класса Java

Tags: java

Задача: создайте класс с именем ConnectionManager, который управляет фиксированным массивом объектов Connection. Программист - клиент не должен напрямую создавать объекты Connection, а может получать их только с помощью статического метода в классе ConnectionManager. Когда запас объектов у класса ConnectionManager будет исчерпан, он должен вернуть ссылку null.

Вот, что у меня получилось

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static Connection[] limitObjects = new Connection[5];
    public static Connection getObject(){
        return Connection.createNewObject();
    }
}

class Connection{
    private Connection(){}
    public static Connection createNewObject(){
        return new Connection();
    }
}
```

Никак не могу понять, каким образом реализовать это "**Когда запас объектов у класса ConnectionManager будет исчерпан, он должен вернуть ссылку null.**"?.

Comment: Я из .net мира, но предполагаю что по задаче нужно Connection[] превратить встек и в статическом конструкторе его инициализировать (поместить в него 5 объектов Connection), а в методе ConnectionManager.getObject извлекать объект из стека, предварительно проверяя сколько ссылок на Connection осталось, и если их не осталось возвращать null

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но мне кажется, что все должно быть намного проще. Видите ли, я читаю книгу и в ней, до этой задачи, стеки еще не рассматривались)

Comment: Не обязательно стек. Можно ввести статическое поле-счётчик, которое будет фиксировать индекс возвращаемого элемента массива. Счетчик может как увеличиваться, так и уменьшаться, в зависимости от реализуемого вами принципа выборки из массива.

Comment: А можно на решение посмотреть?)

Comment: у вас конструктор у Connection должен быть private по условию

Answer (score 1):

```
class ConnectionManager {
    private static int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 5;
    private static Connection[] limitObjects = new Connection[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    private static int counter = 0;
    static {
      for (int i = 0; i<MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
        limitObjects[i] = Connection.createNewObject();
    }
    public static Connection getObject() {
       return counter == MAX_CONNECTIONS ? null : limitObjects[counter++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм..как вариант. Спасибо)

Comment: @YuriGo, ещё нужно предусмотреть как-то закрытие соединений и удаление их из пула. То есть однажды у вас будет полный пул соединений, но какие-то уже будут не нужны, а новое понадобится, тогда нужно старые закрыть и удалить из пула, а новые чтобы создавались. Например, перед созданием нового соединения можно проверять массив уже созданных и искать в нем закрытые.

Answer (score 0):

И еще как вариант :)

```
class ConnectionManager {
    private static int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 5;
    private static ArrayList<Connection> objects = new ArrayList<>(MAX_CONNECTIONS);

    public static Connection getObject() {
        if (objects.size() == MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Connection connection = Connection.createNewObject();
            objects.add(connection);
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ConnectionManager {
    private static int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 5;
    private static Connection[] limitObjects;
    private static int size = 0;
    static {
        limitObjects = new Connection[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    }
    public static Connection getObject() {
        return size == MAX_CONNECTIONS ? null : (limitObjects[size++] = Connection.createNewObject());
    }
}
```